# dll/runner that returns TAP output for an NUnit test suite?

Tags: testing, nunit, tap

Anyone know uf there's a dll/runner anywhere that returns TAP output from an NUnit test suite?

Comment: This should also be tagged “testing” I think.

Answer (score 1):

Seems unlikely to me, since there is an impedance mismatch. TAP has no concept for what NUnit calls a test, and what TAP calls a test usually corresponds to an NUnit assertion, but not precisely. So I’m not sure how the thing you’re looking for would work at all. (But maybe a heuristic could work well enough.)

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, a simple pass/fail for each TestFixture run would allow the output to be sucked into other TAP results for aggregating results/reports. Maybe it's as simple as a xslt to transform the xml report into TAP